# cart.php returns wanted values just for the last product

Tags: php, html, forms, input, cart

When I click 'Update' it should, for now, return to me an ID of a product and the wanted quantity, but it only returns that result with the last product.
When trying to do that on other products in cart it just returns an empty quotes (for quantity) and an ID number.

Here's my code. cart.php

```
              <?php


              include("functions/functions.php");


               ?>

              <!DOCTYPE html>
              <html>
                  <head>
                      <meta charset="utf-8">
                      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
                      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
                      <title>Prodavnica+</title>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                      <div id="header" class="cf">
                          <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
                          <div id="navbar">
                              <ul>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="index.php"> Home</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="all_products.php"> Products</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="customer/my_account.php"> My Account</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="#"> Sign Up</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="cart.php"> Shopping Card</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a href="#"> Contact Us</a>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </div> <!-- END navbar -->
                          <div id="search">
                              <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                  <input type="text" name="search_query" placeholder="Search Product" />
                                  <input type="submit" name="search_button" value="Search" />

                              </form>
                          </div>
                      </div> <!-- END header -->
                      <?php cart(); ?>
                      <div id="shop-bar">
                          <p>
                              Total items: <?php totalItems() ?>
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              Total price: <?php totalPrice()?>
                          </p>
                          <a href="cart.php"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart">   | </i></a>
                          <span> Welcome Guest! </span>

                      </div> <!-- END shop-bar -->
                      <div id="container">

                          <div id="main">

                              <div id="product-box-cart">

                              <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                  <table>

                                          <thead>
                                              <th>Product</th>
                                              <th>Quantity</th>
                                              <th>Remove</th>
                                              <th>Price</th>
                                          </thead>
                                          <tbody>
                                              <?php

                                                  $total = 0;

                                                  global $con;

                                                  $ip = getIp();

                                                  $run_price = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_add = '$ip'");

                                                  while($row_pro_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)) {

                                                      $pro_id = $row_pro_price['p_id'];
                                                      $pro_qty = $row_pro_price['qty'];

                                                      $run_pro_price2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pro_id'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

                                                      while($row_pro_price2 = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price2)) {

                                                          $pro_price = array($row_pro_price2['product_price']);
                                                          $pro_title = $row_pro_price2['product_title'];
                                                          $product_image = $row_pro_price2['product_image'];
                                                          $single_price = $row_pro_price2['product_price'];



                                                          $pro_price_values = array_sum($pro_price);


                                                          $total += $pro_price_values;





                                              ?>

                                              <tr>
                                          <td>
                                              <h2><?php echo $pro_title ?></h2>
                                              <img src="admin/product_images/<?php echo $product_image;?>">

                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                              <input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="<?php echo $pro_qty; ?>">
                                              <button type="submit" name="qty_btn" value = "<?php echo $pro_id; ?>"> Update </button>

                                          </td>

                                          <td>
                                              <button type="submit" name="remove" value="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>"> Remove </button>


                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                              <?php echo "$" . $single_price; ?>
                                          </td>


                                          </tr>

                                          </tbody>


              <?php }} ?>
                                  </table>

                                  <p>
                                  <b>  Total Value: </b>  <?php  echo "$" . $total;?>
                                  </p>
                                  <div id="check-buttons">
                                  <input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping" />
                                  <a href="checkout.php"><input type="button" value="Checkout" /></a>


                                </div> <!-- end cHECK BUTONS -->
                              </form>
                              <?php
                              if(isset($_POST['qty_btn'])) {


                                $qty = $_POST['qty'];
                                $qty_id = $_POST['qty_btn'];

                                printf($_POST['qty_btn']);
                                printf($_POST['qty']);

                              }elseif(!isset($_POST['qty_btn'])) {
                                if(isset($_POST['remove'])) {

                                  $remove_id = $_POST['remove'];

                                  var_dump($remove_id);
                                }
                              }

                              ?>

                              </div> <!-- END product box -->

                          </div> <!-- END main -->


                          <div id="side">
                              <div id="side-category">
                                  <h2>Categories</h2>
                                  <hr />
                                  <table id="mw">
                                      <tr>
                                          <?php
                                          getBrands();

                                           ?>
                                      </tr>
                                  </table>

                                  <ul>

                                      <?php
                                      getCats();
                                       ?>

                                  </ul>
                              </div><!-- END side-category-->

                          </div> <!-- END side -->

                      </div> <!--END container -->

                      <div id="footer">
                          <p>&copy; 2018 by Djordje Stamenkovic</p>
                      </div> <!-- END footer -->

                  </body>
              </html>
```

Yesterday I posted a similar question for this same cart.php where I had one button for the whole cart but without any solution a tried a different approach and it got me to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `form` - all defined inputs are sent to the next page and are there accessible by their `name`.

If you now define more fields with the same name - you do that because you loop over different products - you are not able to access the correct values after submitting

Your structure

```
<form action>
   while (...) { 
       <input name="qty" value="...">
       <button submit>
   }
</form>
```

so you defined multiple `input` with the same name `qty`

Better define multiple `form` with only one input name="qty". One form for each each product

```
while (...) {
    <form action>        
       <input name="qty" value="...">
       <button submit>
   </form>
}
```